# Why does pprint module sorts dict keys differently from print?

Tags: python

`pprint` sorts dicts keys alphabetically, `print` sorts them in default order.

```
from pprint import pprint
d = {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2, 'baz': 3}

pprint(d)
# {'bar': 2, 'baz': 3, 'foo': 1}

print d
# {'baz': 3, 'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}
```

The documentation of `pprint` mentions this, but does not say why. Why the discrepancy?

Comment: It's not correct to say `print sorts them in default order`.  The whole point is that print *doesn't* sort them, whereas `pprint` explicitly sorts them.  `print` merely uses the order the keys are returned by the dict's iterator behavior, an order that is not defined and may vary across implementations and machines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pprint` stands for "pretty print", also implying "pleasing to the human eye, and easily read by humans". Sorting the `dict` keys just follows that aim, `pprint` isn't supposed to be primarily fast (sorting the keys adds a penalty), but, errr, pretty. :)

`print` on the other hand "just prints", as fast as possible. Actually the discrepancy here is between `dict`'s `__str__` and `pprint`'s specially crafted string conversion.

Comment: So, "just because the way it is", then?

Comment: No, because it was written that way, with the purpose at hand in mind. pprint is e.g. used for debugging, and sorting the keys makes finding the info you're looking for much easier.

Answer (score 0):

`pprint` had to probably implement something different from ordinary `print` as it's told to be *pretty*. Well, the output still isn't pretty, but at least sorted.

Printing dictionaries using `print` is most probably connected with their internal implementation (trees? hash tables?). Note that dictionaries require elements to be hashable, so this is where I'd be looking for some ordering rules. In my case, if I populate dictionary with positive integers, my output is sorted (`hash(int)==int`). Whatever the rule is, the `print` statement just travel the dictionary in most convenient and fastest way it can, and any particular order can't be assumed.

Comment: No, if you populate the dictionary with the particular positive integers that you happened to choose then the output is sorted, but if you had chosen different integers it might not have been sorted: e.g. `dict.fromkeys([1,8])` -> `{8: None, 1: None}`. dict's `str` method outputs keys in the order they are stored in the hash table, `pprint` doesn't use `str` so it can sort the keys and insert newlines where appropriate.

Comment: @duncan, of course you're right, I've done this quick test with adding sequence of numbers, but it actually says nothing. Interesting how one can reveal underlying implementation by examining order of elements while iterating (from your example it looks like a hash table starts with 8 buckets).